# Groovy & Processing -- how to obtain a reference to applet?

Tags: java, groovy, processing

I wrote a program in Java, which uses the PApplet class from Processing. This class instantiates a PApplet object behind the scene. I needed e reference to this object in some other classes, so I used this little trick:

```
public class MyApplet extends PApplet {
  public static MyApplet myApplet;
  // plus other various fields...

  // initializing block
  {
    myApplet = this;
  }

  // stuff...
}

// Now in some other class
import static MyApplet.myApplet;
class OtherClass {
  // here I can use the reference to myapplet
  myApplet.whatever();
}
```

All worked nice and cool. But then I wanted to translate all this code into Groovy. The problem is Groovy's closures take a "snapshot" of the variables very early, at the time of their declaration -- so they see the `myapplet` field as not being initialized. Groovy does its stuff very early, even earlier than the initialization block. At least that's my explanation of why `myapplet` is seen as null in Groovy classes.

How can I circumvent this? How can I get hold of a reference to the applet object which `PApplet` builds behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Does the [`@Lazy` annotation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Lazy+transformation) get round it?  ie:

```
public class MyApplet extends PApplet {
  @Lazy static MyApplet instance = { -> MyApplet._instance }()
  private static _instance 
  public MyApplet() {
    MyApplet._instance = this
  }
}
```

then call `MyApplet.instance`

I would say that this static instance approach is a fairly brittle, and you may want to consider passing the Applet instance into your other class explicitly, or use some other method instead of the taking the static global instance route.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass a reference to your `PApplet` instance into your `OtherClass` instance?

```
public class MyApplet extends PApplet {
    void setup () {
        OtherClass otherClassInstance = new OtherClass(this);
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    public OtherClass (PApplet p) {
        //p.whatever();
    }
}
```

If you need access to PApplet's fields/methods later than `OtherClass`'s constructor, store that reference in a local member:

```
class OtherClass {
    private PApplet p;
    public OtherClass (PApplet p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    private void someMethod () {
        //p.whatever();
    }
}
```

That's the usual way to use Processing within Java.

Comment: OK, I get it. I pass the ref explicitly to the OtherClass constructor, each time a new instance is created. It might work, I'll give it a try. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it: I created a Glue class in plain Java, which sets the static reference to myApplet. Then I extend this Glue in Groovy:

```
// Java
class Glue extends PApplet {
  static Glue myApplet;
  // initialization block
  {
  myApplet = this;
  }
}

// Then Groovy
class MyApplet extends Glue {
  // ...
}

// And Groovy again
import static Glue.myApplet
class OtherClass {
  myApplet.whatever()
}
```

It works like a charm!

I need to do this because there are thousands of instances of OtherClass, and it would be impractical to send them thousands of copies of a reference to the same applet object (which is unique).

This solution sets the reference to the static field before Groovy does its stuff.

Comment: Actually, that would not be impractical at all.  A reference in Java is not an additional object, it just points to the original object (in this case, the single instance of `MyApplet`).  Using statics as globals is generally considered poor design; you should be very wary of doing so.